# POP3 and SMTP over port 80

Tags: nginx, email, proxy, http

TL;DR I need connect mail clients over port 80.

I have a requirement to allow to mail clients connect to my mail provider over port 80.

Some users of my company works in clients workplace. In some of this workplaces they have access to internet only through a proxy server, who only allow data over the 80 and 443 port. Because of this, they can not use any email client software to connect to our corporate mail (this email server is in a shared hosting with cpanel).

So, i has this crazy idea of use nginx as a proxy service, redirecting a specific subdomain in port 80 to my host provider:port. In example

> smtp.mycompany.com:80 -> mail.hostingprovider.com:25
>
> pop3.mycompany.com:80 -> mail.hostingprovider.com:110

There is some way i can achieve this?

Comment: How about a web mail interface or a VPN?

Comment: Im not sure about use a vpn. As far as i know they rely on a proxy to go outside their network, and that proxy only allows connection over the 443 and 80 ports.
And about the webmail interface, they dont have the habit of delete mails, so their accounts quicky become full.

Comment: How does the fact that they don't delete their emails have any bearing on giving them access to email via webmail?

Comment: It's doesn't really. They have access to squirrelmail, horde, roundcube but don't use it because they find it ugly. The quota per mail in this shared hosting is 50mb. Today that quota is reached in 20 mails.

Comment: This is just stupid. Places with proxy on 80/443 will probably check if the connection is HTTP. And Client SMTP should be done on 587. If you change the 25 SMTP port you will break the external world from sending mails to your server.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski Where in the documentation i can view an example of how to redirect to another server?

Comment: Install a VPN on your clients that operate via http/https.  Do smtp/pop normally.

Answer (score 1):

I searched Google for "Nginx as email proxy server" and found this article on the Nginx website on [how to use Nginx as an email proxy server](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/mail-proxy/). Just change the port in the configuration.

Perhaps you should try reading the official documentation then ask a question if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I already read it, but for me is not clear where i do the redirect to the actual mail server. Is the http auth part? The configuration give me an idea of the mail server and the nginx server are in the same host, but, what if they are in totally different hosts?

Comment: You need to fully explain your problem and what you've tried, what didn't work, in your question. I would look into proxy_pass.